# Symfony - Cannot fetch ColumnMap for undefined column

Tags: php, symfony1, propel

Bang Bang BANG.... (sound of my head hitting the wall)

> Unable to execute UPDATE statement. [wrapped: Cannot fetch ColumnMap for undefined column:: DISCOUNTCODE

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838815/problems-with-database-relations-with-symfony-framework-cannot-fetch-tablemap-f) but it wasn't any help to me as I do not have any table prefixes in my propel.ini

Does anyone know what could be causing this error?
And yes I have cleared my cache, rebuilt my schema and model countless times.
The only clue to my problem is that it does work on my localhost, and not on the live server.

If I look in the base class I do see `const DISCOUNTCODE = orders.DISCOUNTCODE`

Please help...

Comment: Do you really have `const DISCOUNTCODE = orders.DISCOUNTCODE` ? I guess that you should have something like `const DISCOUNTCODE = "orders.DISCOUNTCODE";`. BTW which version of Symfony / Propel do you use ?

Comment: Check this file : http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/71983/

Comment: Sorry, I have DISCOUNTCODE = "orders.DISCOUNTCODE". Running Symfony 1.2 with Propel 2.1 i think..

Comment: Thanks for that post, but it wasn't much help. I build my database first, then generate my schema.yml file from the command line with propel:build-schema. The problem is that Propel doesn't think a column I'm trying to insert into exists??? Very strange.

Comment: I guess you have Symfony 1.2 + Propel 1.2 (never heard of a 2.1 yet). The only thing I can suggest you is to ensure that you have **exactly** the same files on your local and live environments, e.g. for some obscure "access right" reason you cannot copy some files on your live server. Do you use an FTP client ? In this case I suggest to use **FileZilla**, which has an nice **diff** feature.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this many times. We may have had different problems but what's worked for me is completely deleting the model map files then rebuilding everything:

```
rm -rf lib/model/map/*
```